# What is difference passing YES and NO to 'endEditing' method call

Tags: ios, objective-c

To resign first responder of subviews of a view, I may call `endEditing` method. I saw `YES` as `BOOL` parameter to pass into in sample code as

```
[self.view endEditing:YES]
```

I had 3 textfields in View which I called method, and it works to remove keyboard of any of 3 subviews.

While I change parameter to NO as

```
[self.view endEditing:NO]
```

I saw nothing different, it seemed working in same way.

I think I didn't make it clear that what really confused me. I read doc but didn't know what would happen if I passed YES but one of subview refused to resign...how could it?

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/endEditing:

Comment: Press `option` + click in the function and you can see information

Answer (score 1):

The documentation...

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html

Specifies...

> ## Parameters
>
> force
>
> Specify YES to force the first responder to resign, regardless
> of whether it wants to do so.

Always check the documentation to find out what parameters mean. Most of the APIs are VERY well documented by Apple.

Comment: My point is what if first responder refuse, if it could, to resign? Actually I didn't see any side effect when I passed NO to function call.

Comment: @AlanHoo if the view was willing to resign first responder then passing YES or NO will make no difference. Passing YES will resign it whether or not it wants to. Tbh I'm just repeating what the docs are saying. I'm not sure what you are asking now. Look at the docs. It isn't ambiguous.